# Use JQuery cropper plug in with angular file upload

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I'm trying to crop an image after it's uploaded. I'm using the Jquery [Cropper](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropper/blob/v0.11.1/README.md) plugin. I'm able to crop when I use a static image however I'm having trouble getting the cropper to show up on an image that has been uploaded. How can I initialize the cropping on an image after it's uploaded?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q8c5gqh9/)

HTML

```
<input type='file' ng-model-instant onchange="angular.element(this).scope().imageUpload(this)" />
  <br>
 <div class="cropper-example-1">
   <img ng-src="{{ img_url }}">
 </div>
 <br><br><br>
 <h4>Static Working example</h4>
 <div class="cropper-example-2">
   <img src="http://i.imgur.com/86S751Y.jpg">          
 </div>
```

JS

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.imageUpload = function(element){
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = $scope.imageIsLoaded;
    reader.readAsDataURL(element.files[0]);
  }

  $scope.imageIsLoaded = function(e){
    $scope.$apply(function() {
      $scope.img_url = e.target.result;
      $('.cropper-example-1 > img').cropper({
          aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
          autoCropArea: 0.65,
          strict: false,
          guides: false,
          highlight: false,
          dragCrop: false,
          cropBoxMovable: false,
          cropBoxResizable: false
      });
    });
  }
  $('.cropper-example-2 > img').cropper({
      aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
      autoCropArea: 0.65,
      strict: false,
      guides: false,
      highlight: false,
      dragCrop: false,
      cropBoxMovable: false,
      cropBoxResizable: false
  });
}
```

Comment: I used the same library before but suddenly the library stop working properly so I searched the internet but I found nothing so I suggest try to search/use other library but if you really want to use it here the angular version of it: https://github.com/koorgoo/ngCropper

Comment: @AlbertoI.N.J. thanks, I saw a few of these wrappers. What did you replace Cropper with? Do you still use it or are you using a different library? I tried [ngImgCrop](https://github.com/alexk111/ngImgCrop) but couldn't get it working with angular 1.4

Comment: For the mean time I'm using `ngImgCrop` but I've done several modification for it work.

Comment: @AlbertoI.N.J. have you tried [guillotine](https://github.com/matiasgagliano/guillotine)?